# "Class" constants and constructor: how to implement?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have something like this implemented in javasript please:

```
var hat = new Hat(Hat.Color.RED, Hat.Size.MEDIUM);
```

How can I do it please (tried to mess with function `prototype` but with a little success)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Hat` will be a constructor function:

```
function Hat(color, size) {
    this.id = "X"+color+size; // or anything else
}
```

On the prototype are "methods" for `Hat` instances:

```
Hat.prototype.raise = function() {
    ...
};
```

But the constants are properties of the Function object:

```
Hat.Color = {
    RED: "F00",
    GREEN: "0F0",
    ...
};
Hat.Size = {
    MEDIUM: 0,
    LARGE: 1,
    ...
};
```

If your library implements the "extend" function correctly (nothing special on constructors), this should also work:

```
Object.extend(Hat, {
    Color: {RED: "F00", GREEN: "0F0", ...},
    Size: = {MEDIUM: 0, LARGE: 1, ...},
});
```

Comment: Very interesting (`extend`)! A piggyback question if I may: why couldn't I write `Hat.prototype.Color = {...}`?

Comment: That would mean that all Hat instances would inherit that Color property. You would not be able to use them as constructor arguments.

Comment: jQuery.extend is one example, there are plenty of js libraries with the extend function.

Comment: I would just edit the answer, because `Object.extend` is simply `undefined`.

Comment: Also, just for the record, I've slightly upgraded my own code with `Object.freeze()` to keep the constants constant: `$.extend(Hat, Object.freeze({Color: {...}, Size: {...}});`.

Comment: @BreakPhreak: No, Benjamin is right (and e.g. my lib implements it as a static property on `Object`). Btw, jQuery will happily forget that the copied properties were frozen; You want ...`.extend(Hat, {Color: Object.freeze({...}), Size:Object.freeze({...})});`

Answer (score 6):

You can do that if you create a `Hat` constructor function like this:

```
function Hat(color, size) {
  this.color = color;
  this.size = size;
}
Hat.Color = {
  RED: "#F00",
  GREEN: "#0F0",
  BLUE: "#00F"
};
Hat.Size = {
  SMALL: 0,
  MEDIUM: 1,
  LARGE: 2
}
```

You can then create a `new Hat` and get its properties

```
var hat = new Hat(Hat.Color.RED, Hat.Size.MEDIUM);
var hatColor = hat.color; // "#F00"
```

Comment: Does it imply that `Hat.Color` etc **must** be declared after `function Hat` is declared? Also, can the function be declared via `var Hat = function() { ... };` syntax?

Comment: @BreakPhreak You can use either `function Hat() {}`, or `var Hat = function()`. Using the first will allow you to declare `Hat.Color` before or after `Hat` is declared, because `Hat` is hoisted. If you use the second, `Hat.Color` **must** be declared after `Hat`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the functional inheritance way. It distinguishes between private and publci methods and variables.

```
var Hat = function (color, size) {
  var that = {};
  that.Color = { RED: 'abc'};  // object containing all colors
  that.Size = { Medium: 'big'}; // object containing all sizes
  that.print = function () {
    //I am a public method
  };
  // private methods can be defined here.
  // public methods can be appended to that.
  return that;  // will return that i.e. all public methods and variables
}
```

Comment: ...but he wanted a static variable.